# Why does this method of proof for $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}$ not apply for $\mathbb{F}_{p}$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}$ be the algebraic closure of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Consider $F:= \overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}(x,y)$ and let $K:=\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}(x^{p},y^{p})$.

Below I will show that $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}(x,y)/\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}(x^{p},y^{p})$ is not a simple extension by exhibiting infinitely many intermediate subfields. My concern is, I was told that the same proof does not work if we simply consider $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and not its algebraic closure. However, I have come across proofs of this result that proceed the same way. So I would like to ask is: in what way does the method of proof need to be changed (if at all)? Since I have seen a handful of proofs that look almost identical, there must be something subtle that's different.

PROOF: We can show that $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}(x,y)/\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}(x^{p},y^{p})$ is not a simple extension by using the result that $K/F$ (finite) extension is simple iff there exist finitely many subfields of $K$ containing $F$. This is done by noting that $[F : K] = p^{2}$ and that the subfields $F(x + cy)$ for $c \in\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}$ are all of degree $p$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}(x^{p}, y^{p})$, noting that

$$(x+cy)^{p} = x^{p} + c^{p}y^{p} \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}(x^{p}, y^{p})$$

Then we can conclude by showing that if $F(x+c_{1}y) = F(x+c_{2}y)$ for $c_{1} \neq c_{2}$ then we would have that $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}(x,y) = F(x+cy)$ which is impossible by degree considerations. Hence there are infinitely many such subfields and so the extension cannot be simple.

Comment: This proof will not work if we replace $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ by $\Bbb{F}_p$, because there are only finitely many $c\in\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: The proof does work but one must take $c \in \mathbb F_p(x^p,y^p)$. See the *Edit* to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what "they" told you but the extension $E=\mathbb{F}_{p}(x,y)/L=\mathbb{F}_{p}(x^{p},y^{p})$ **is** also not simple!

Indeed $[E:L]=p^2$, whereas any rational function $\phi(x,y)=\frac{P(x,y}{Q(x,y)}\in E$ (with $P(x,y), Q(x,y)\neq0\in \mathbb{F}_{p}[x,y]$) satisfies $\phi(x,y)^p=\frac{P(x^p,y^p)}{Q(x^p,y^p)}\in \mathbb{F}_{p}(x^{p},y^{p})=L$, so that the degree of $\phi(x,y)$ over $L$ is at most $p$ and we thus cannot have  $L(\phi)=E$.
In other words no element  $\phi \in \mathbb{F}_{p}(x,y)=E$ generates the extension $E/L$, which is thus not simple.

**Remarks**
a) You had better forget about this business of finitely many intermediate fields, which is  a red herring for the problem at hand.
b) Did you notice that I used $(P(x,y))^p=P(x^p,y^p)$ ? Do you believe that ? Why ?

**Edit**
Since mistertanaka asks for an infinite family of intermediate fields $  L=\mathbb F_p(x^p,y^p) \subset M \subset E=\mathbb F_p(x,y)$, here is such a family.
  To  $\phi\in L=\mathbb F_p(x^p,y^p)$ associate the field $M_\phi=L(x+\phi\cdot y)$.
I claim that the $M_\phi$ are different for different $\phi$ which will immediately show the existence of an  infinite family of intermediate fields $M_\phi$.
So,  suppose $\phi\neq \psi$ but $M_{\phi}=M_{\psi}=:M$.
 Then $M$ has degree $\leq p$ and $x+\phi\cdot y,x+\psi\cdot y\in M$ so that $(\phi-\psi)\cdot y\in M$ and thus $y\in M$.
But this implies $x\in M$ too so that $M=\mathbb F_p(x,y)=E$, which is absurd because $[M:L]\leq p$, whereas $[E:L]=p^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope there wasn't anything too ambiguous in my post, but no one told be that the extension is not simple. Just that the proof given for showing $\overline{E}/\overline{F}$ is not simple is not the same as $E/F$. The reason I asked is because I saw a handful of proofs using the exact same approach.

You do provide a nice way of seeing that $E/L$ is not simple, but the question specifically asks to show this by exhibiting infinitely many intermediate subfields... so I'm trying to somehow make that work.

Comment: Dear mistertanaka, at your request I have added an edit exhibiting  an infinite number of very explicit intermediate subfields.

Answer (score 1):

There are only finitely many choices for $c \in \mathbf{F}_p$.

Let $E/F$ be any field extension in characteristic $p$. If we take the compositums $E' = \overline{\mathbf{F}}_p E$ and $F' = \overline{\mathbf{F}}_p F$, I assert that $E/F$ is simple if and only if $E'/F'$ is simple.

Comment: This makes sense. It seems odd to me that I have seen a handful of proofs that claim to exhibit infinitely intermediate subfields of the form $F(x+cy)$ for $F = \mathbb{F}_{p}(x^{p}, y^{p})$. Is there a way to modify the proof to work in this case?

Comment: Dear Hurkyl, your compositum $E' = \overline{\mathbf{F}}_p E$ does not make sense unless you suppose that $E$ and $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p$ are subfields of some big field. And in that case your assertion is false, as you can check by taking $F=\mathbb F_p$ and $E=\overline {\mathbb F_p}=$ the big field.

Comment: @Georges: Bah, you're right! I was just thinking of the transcendental part, and I'm *sure* what I'm actually *thinking* is right, but I need to think more on how to express it properly. :(